# Stream desktop (linux) with FFMPEG to VLC

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, linux

Hey guys how can I stream my desktop to vlc I did found some examples but they do not work;First I need to start ffserver with some configs example here https://www.organicdesign.co.nz/Simple_video_streaming_with_ffserver then when I start stream with

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 127.0.0.1/cam1.ffm
```

I got an error */dev/video0: No such file or directory*

Answer (score 1):

No need to use ffmpeg here:

Open VLC, go to *Media* > *Open Capture Device* and set *Capture Mode* to *Desktop*

Also see:

- https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/screen/
- https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line/#Desktop.2FScreen_grab_options